# trpc v10 - Error: Query data cannot be undefined

Tags: next.js, react-query, trpc.io, t3

New to trpc. Trying to get basic query functionality but it's not working. Not sure what I'm missing. In v9 it used `createReactQueryHooks()`, but it seems in v10 you only need to use `createTRPCNext()` if I'm not mistaken inside `util/trpc.tsx`.

Error:

```js
next-dev.js:32 Error: Query data cannot be undefined - affected query key: ["greeting"]
    at Object.onSuccess (query.mjs:320:19)
    at resolve (retryer.mjs:64:50)
```

```js
// utils/trpc.ts
export const trpc = createTRPCNext<AppRouter, SSRContext>({
    config({ ctx }) {
        return {
            transformer: superjson, // optional - adds superjson serialization
            links: [
                httpBatchLink({
                    /**
                     * If you want to use SSR, you need to use the server's full URL
                     * @link https://trpc.io/docs/ssr
                     **/
                    url: `${getBaseUrl()}/api/trpc`,
                }),
            ],
            /**
             * @link https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient
             **/
            // queryClientConfig: { defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 60 } } },
            headers() {
                if (ctx?.req) {
                    // To use SSR properly, you need to forward the client's headers to the server
                    // This is so you can pass through things like cookies when we're server-side rendering
                    // If you're using Node 18, omit the "connection" header
                    const {
                        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
                        connection: _connection,
                        ...headers
                    } = ctx.req.headers;
                    return {
                        ...headers,
                        // Optional: inform server that it's an SSR request
                        "x-ssr": "1",
                    };
                }
                return {};
            },
        };
    },
    ssr: true,
});
```

```js
// server/router/_app.ts
import { t } from '@/server/trpc';
import { userRouter } from '@/server/router/user';
import { postRouter } from '@/server/router/posts';
import { authRouter } from './authy';

export const appRouter = t.router({
    user: userRouter,
    post: postRouter,
    authy: authRouter,
    greeting: t.procedure.query(() => 'hello tRPC v10!'),
});

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter;
```

```js
// server/router/authy.ts
import { t } from "@/server/trpc";
import * as trpc from "@trpc/server";
import { z } from "zod";

export const authRouter = t.router({
    hello: t.procedure
        // using zod schema to validate and infer input values
        .input(
            z.object({
                    text: z.string().nullish(),
                })
                .nullish().optional()
        )
        .query(({ input }) => {
            return {
                greeting: `hello ${input?.text ?? "world"}`,
            };
        }),
});

export type AuthRouter = typeof authRouter;
```

None of the routes work. They all show a similar error.

```js
// pages/test.tsx
import React from "react";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import { trpc } from "@/utils/trpc";

const TestPage: NextPage = () => {
    const helloNoArgs = trpc.authy.hello.useQuery();
    const helloWithArgs = trpc.authy.hello.useQuery({ text: "client" });
    const greeting = trpc.greeting.useQuery();

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World Example</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    helloNoArgs ({helloNoArgs.status}):{" "}
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(helloNoArgs.data, null, 2)}</pre>
                </li>
                <li>
                    helloWithArgs ({helloWithArgs.status}):{" "}
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(helloWithArgs.data, null, 2)}</pre>
                </li>
                <li>
                    greeting ({greeting.status}):{" "}
                    <pre>{JSON.stringify(greeting.data, null, 2)}</pre>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TestPage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omgosh... it was because I was using "^10.0.0-proxy-beta.7" and not "^10.0.0-proxy-beta.8"

Edit: Somehow I had another error and encountered my own question again 22 days later and solved it again. In general, when using trpc it seems updating to all the `@next` packages is best as it seems to be somewhat easy to have packages not talking to each other as they improve.

https://trpc.io/docs/v10/quickstart#installation-snippets

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using superjson. You need to add superjson transformer at initTRPC.

## routers/router/_app.ts

```
import { initTRPC } from '@trpc/server';
import superjson from 'superjson';
export const t = initTRPC.create({
  transformer: superjson,
});
```

more detailed instruction can be found here: [TRPC v10](https://trpc.io/docs/v10/data-transformers)

Answer (score 0):

On my side I was using a mocked `trpc` server that was not using `superjson` (whereas the real one was). I just used `superjson.serialize(...)` before adding the JSON body to my response (in my server mock), then it worked :)